# CSS - remove an element from its parent with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Using media queries in CSS, is it possible to remove an element from its parent, like so:

Default:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

With media query:

```
<div id="parent"></div>
<div id="child"></div>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can't move items in the DOM with CSS, you will need to use javascript. Why is it you are trying to do this? Perhaps there is another solution that could be explored.

Comment: you can change sibling element order but this is not possible using CSS only

Comment: @ Sam: I'd like to move an element that was absolutely positioned in relation to its parent to be on its own (placed under rather than inside its parent) on smaller screen resolutions.

Comment: can you show your css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, no. It is not possible for CSS media queries to change the DOM order (Flex [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) can do something similar, maybe it can also help).

**But:** 
You can achieve the desired effect differently. By cloning the item (so that you have it once inside, once outside the parent) and then showing/hiding the respective one, you will mimic the effect you are looking for.

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="child child-outer"></div>
```

Now simply toggle between styles

```
.child-inner { display: block; }
.child-outer { display: none; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .child-inner { display: none; }
    .child-outer { display: block; }
}
```